# Alternative ways to access Keycloak REST API

Tags: keycloak

We are trying to configure keycloak with the REST API (e.g. adding users, roles etc). We would like to use the REST API but it seems only Java and Javascript is officially supported which I find strange for a REST API. Isn't it possible to use say a Python REST client to access Keycloak ?

Comment: It's a RESTful API. You can program your client in any language.

Comment: http://www.keycloak.org/docs/rest-api/#_userrepresentation

Answer (score 3):

Keycloak provides a `RESTful API`, which pretty much means that you can use it with any programming language you want, not just `Java` or `JavaScript`.

And you are correct, the **official** Keycloak admin is provided in `Java`. But nothing can stop you from [looking at the docs](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/rest-api/) and writing yours.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few open source Python Keycloak clients available:

- https://github.com/Peter-Slump/python-keycloak-client
- https://bitbucket.org/agriness/python-keycloak